# How to add compiler option for mosquitto library in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, mosquitto, compiler-options

so I am wanting to interface the mosquitto mqtt library into qt creator (c++), to create a graphical program for using mqtt. I am trying to figure out how to add the -lmosquitto compiler option, I have seen similar posts about adding c++ compiler options by using line shown below inside the .pro file

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += compiler option here
```

I tried to add the -lmosquitto compiler option in the same way shown below

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lmosquitto
```

but I still get errors saying undefined reference to 'function names'

Does anyone know how to add compiler options for libraries into qt

FYI: I am using ubuntu, in qt creator I am creating widget application, and I am sure the -lmosquitto is the correct option as I can compile code wrote in text editor from command line using it.

Any help with this would be great,

Thanks in advance,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general advice I would give you is, to use `CMake` with `QT`. `QT` supports `CMake` since `QT5` IIRC, and since `QT6` it is the standard build tool if I'm not mistaken. The benefit of using `CMake` is that you will find more answers to your questions.

That being said, if you still wish to use `qmake` instead of `CMake` then last I checked, you will need to add a line like this to your `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/your/mosquitto_library -lmosquitto
```

Notice the `-L` flag where you specify the library path. This is essentially what is missing from your `CXX` flags.

Comment: Great thank you, is the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS line still needed then or is it just the LIBS line like you mentioned

Comment: It's been 4 years since I've used `qmake` but I don't think they changed it. I.e. I think you just need to add `LIBS += ...` note the `+=`. However `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -L... -l...` should have the same effect. The idea behind `LIBS += ...` is about readability. You can add as many lines starting with that variable and operand as much as you want, making the `.pro` file "human more readable"

Comment: Great Will do Thank you so much for your help, this worked great. You saved me a lot of time struggling